# Laravel/Homestead Invalid IP Address

Tags: laravel, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I am using Laravel 6.2, Vagrant 2.2.6 and VirtualBox 5.2. Followed the tutorial for Homestead setup. But when I visited myapp.local (out of the box without modifying any code), I got the following error message:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
```

(Please see my comment below explaining why I was getting this error)

**Mistakenly**, I modified the ip address in my Homestead.yaml file and now, no matter what I do, I am getting the following error message.

```
Network settings specified in your Vagrantfile define an invalid
IP address. Please review the error message below and update your
Vagrantfile network settings:

  Address: 192.168.10:10
  Netmask: 
  Error: invalid address
```

Example:

```
machine1234:Homestead my_user_name$ vagrant destroy
    homestead: Are you sure you want to destroy the 'homestead' VM? [y/N] y
==> homestead: Destroying VM and associated drives...
machine1234:Homestead my_user_name$ vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> homestead: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '9.2.0' is up to date...
==> homestead: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
Network settings specified in your Vagrantfile define an invalid
IP address. Please review the error message below and update your
Vagrantfile network settings:

  Address: 192.168.10:10
  Netmask: 
  Error: invalid address
```

Homestead.yaml looks like this:

```
> --- ip: "192.168.10:10" memory: 2048 cpus: 2 provider: virtualbox
> 
> authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
> 
> keys:
>     - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
> 
> folders:
>     - map: ~/Sites/myapp
>       to: /home/vagrant/myapp
> 
> 
> sites:
>     - map: myapp.local
>       to: /home/vagrant/myapp/public

> databases:
>     - MY_APP_DEV
> 
> features:
>     - mariadb: false
>     - ohmyzsh: false
>     - webdriver: false "Homestead.yaml" 41L, 667C
```

Any idea on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: The reason why I was getting the "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161" error was because in my Homestead.yaml file I had myapp.dev and in my /etc/hosts file I had myapp.local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your IP address has a colon!

**Change:**

```
  Address: 192.168.10:10
```

**To:**

```
  Address: 192.168.10.10
```

Comment: @KalC It's okay :) We all make typos. Happy Coding!